# Is it possible to put the contents of a bash script variable into the windows "ctrl-c" copy function

Tags: bash, shell, copy, paste

Can I assign a value to the windows "ctr-c" copy function through a bash script?

I would like to write a bash script that will find regex matches in a long string (from a text file), then assign each line containing a match to the windows "ctr-c" / "ctr-v" function. I have no idea how to assign a value to the windows copy function, is this possible?

Note: I am writing/running this script on a server I have SSHed into, I am running windows 10 and the server is running Debian. I assume that the server has its own "clipboard" like my windows 10 computer does (ctrl-v/c). My goal is to assign a value to my windows clipboard, not the servers clipboard. If it would make my task easier, I can just run the script on my windows 10 computer. I am only running it on the server in order to access some specific Linux tools that are installed on it.

I expect to run the script, then press "ctr-v" to paste what the script assigned to my "clipboard"

Comment: Too broad, and probably belongs on SuperUser. (You can use linux tools on windows with git-bash or WSL or a number of other ways, but you need a command that copies its input to the clipboard which may exist, I just don't know it, SuperUser might be a better place to get that help.)

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, you want to share the clipboard on the remote server with the one on Windows? Since you only specify "ssh" as infrastructure to connect to both, this is not possible, because an ssh session does not have the concept of a clipboard. A clipboard is part of a Window Manager, and unless you do not connect to a remote Window Manager session (in a similar way that, for instance, Remote Desktop can connect to another Windows computer), it is pointless of talking about clipboards.

You could pass however the string back to the caller side, for instance by writing it to stdout and collect stdout on your Windows machine, and then use some tool to store it into the Windows clipboard.